# filter() function doesn't work after ANOVA code

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I wrote this code to test the simple effect of stress at each level of gender at time2 (I have t1 and t2 which t1 result of simple interaction effect was not significant in the previous section I ran.) I want to filter time so that just the effect is shown for t2:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rstatix)

stress.effect <- performance %>%
  group_by(time, gender) %>%
  anova_test(dv = score, wid = id, between = stress)

stress.effect %>% filter(time == "t2")
```

But I get the error below:

```
Error in `vec_slice()`:
! `x` must be a vector, not a <grouped_anova_test/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame/rstatix_test> object.
---
Backtrace:
  1. stress.effect %>% filter(time == "t2")
  3. dplyr:::filter.data.frame(., time == "t2")
  5. dplyr:::dplyr_row_slice.data.frame(.data, loc, preserve = .preserve)
 10. vctrs::vec_slice(data, i)
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.
```

Can someone help me understand why there is such error and what should I do to fix it?

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) on making a reproducible example that is easier for folks to help with. Where does `anova_test` come from, and what does it return?

Comment: `filter` works on a dataframe not an anova object